# Making my building blocks modular

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling the different parts of my scenes as modular building blocks. This way, I can make up different rooms/scenes starting from these different blocks. Basic building blocks are:

**Wall:**

[image: wall]

**Floor tile:**

[image: floor-tile]

**Door:**

[image: door]

**Open corner:**

[image: open-corner]

**Closed corner:**

[image: closed-corner]

There are more building blocks, but these are the basic ones. Main problem is that, when I build a scene, I somehow end up being unable to close my rooms using ONLY these building blocks. In the next screenshots you will appreciate this phenomena:

[image: problem-1]
[image: problem-2]

As you can see, it is impossible to close the red gap with a basic wall building block, without having an overlap between them.

Much in the same way, you can appreciate that the basic floor tiles building block will get past out of walls.

I have to choose between mantaining reusability (via building extra helper building blocks), or breaking this reusability by directly modifying each room separately.

Can you come up with a solution? I would really like to keep re-usability, since I'll be building dozens or more rooms, and I wouldn't really like to modify each of those independently.

Here are more screenshots of the room I'm building right now:
[image: room-01][image: room-02]

---

**EDIT:**
Solved! Thanks to [@Carlo's indications](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64736/27601) about the *Open Corner block*, now my two problems have been solved very easily. In a nutshell, the problem was that I wasn't having into account the thickness of the Open Corner building block. Here is a screenshot of the new scene:

[image: final-room01]
[image: final-room02]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the **Open corner** piece.

It has been created inside the bounding box space defined by the tile size (2x2 units). That would work nice till the wall is sketched as a line, but in this case thickness (T) is taken into account. In order to achieve a regular grid behaviour, you should increase the dimension of the piece by the thickness of the wall, resulting in a (2+T)x(2+T) tile

[image]

Comment: Hey @Carlo, thank you for the answer. So, considering the Open Corner Piece, you would make it inside of a (2+T)*(2+T) box, right? I will try it and tell you what I got to. Do you think the Closed Corner Piece will need to be remodelled too?

Comment: In order to follow the rule that you seemed to follow for the other pieces (aka the exterior face of the wall aligned with the boundary of the tile), the final length should be that. No, the Closed Corner piece is fine. You can easily check your pieces shape by positining two base wall pieces alingned with the grid one perpendicular to the other. You'll see that something is missing and must be build in order to join the properly.

Comment: Good news Carlo. What you said is absolutely right, and solved my two issues at the same time! I can't thank you enough. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 7):

Modular assets need quite a lot of planing. First you need to specify a grid size. This might be a floor tile, it also might be bound to a certain measurement like the width of a door frame. Measured from the borders of your base grid, you then need to inset the interior walls and outset the exterior walls. The gap between will be the thickness of the wall.

The next point you need to consider carefully, is the center of your wall. If your grid starts at either the inside or the outside, your modules won't have the right size. You want to have Blender's grid lines exactly in the middle between your inner and your outer wall (see the green lines in the screenshot below. Also notice the slightly thicker lines of Blender's major Unit grid).

[image: grid layout and median axies]

My walls are exactly two Blender Units wide. The floor tiles will then be perfect squares and also have two Blender units in width and height. The floor will overlap with the wall but it won't show from the outside, since it goes only to half the size of the wall's width.

[image: result]

There you go, perfectly matching tiles in all directions.

Here's a .blend file with a very basic setup.

[image]

PS: You also want to remove all hidden faces. They are unnecessary in nearly every setup, as long as you don't want to create gaps in the wall, where the sides are visible. The floor tiles in my file are just planes but the principle is the same as it is for the walls.

Comment: Hey metaphor_set, I like how you approached the modular-like mindset, and I'm sure the .blend file you attached will help me in future building blocks :) However @Carlo's answer most straightforwardly solved my immediate problem, and thus I had to choose it as the accepted one. But your answer is beautiful as well, so thank you very much for your time!